# How to Totally remove Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I don't want to use Asset Pipeline for a Rails 3.1 application, so I put in my config/application.rb the line for disable it  `config.assets.enabled = false`

Also I remove the assets gems, because I don't want to use sassl , cofeescript and uglyfier

My question is:

1. How to complete remove assets pipeline because when I generate a scaffold , it create the files in asset
2. Where I get the jquery and rails.js files to put it in my public directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators) for configuring generators. in order to prevent asset generation, set assets to false.

You can get JQuery from the jquery website. You can then get the unobtrusive javascript adapter for jquery from [github](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

Comment: When you say "set assets to false" exactly what configuration are you talking about?

Comment: The assets setting on generators. Add A code block similar to the docs only yours will set g.assets To false

Comment: Thanks, I did it, however I think in the end I will use  asset, for avoid future problems.